# Unable to change parent properties

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6, drilldown

I am using foundation [accordian menu](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/accordion-menu.html). What I am trying to achieve is to modify the parent properties of my *li_left_border* class.

The reason I am doing this is because the *li_left_border* class has the URL I am currently on, in this case it is $10, see the picture.

I want to show my drill down as expanded when the site is loaded.

[image]

I have tried:

```
$( ".li_left_border" ).parent().addClass('test');
$( ".li_left_border" ).parent().css('display', 'block');
```

[image]

It will work when the display becomes from none to block, which I have tested in developer F12. The problem is I am unable to change the parent properties, I dont know how to get to the parent ul.

```
<script src="game.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).foundation();
        $( ".li_left_border" ).parents("ul").addClass('test');
        $( ".li_left_border" ).parents("ul").css('display', 'block');
   })
})
</script>
```

Comment: show your part of code.

Comment: can you please add your full code here or in jsfiddle, So We can try on that?

Comment: This is my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/v87qajau/ So what I wanted to achieve is, I am at this page with cash prize $10, I want the $10s to be expanded on pageload.

Comment: Thanks for telling me to use jsfiddle guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `parent`, you get the `li` element, but you want to get the `ul` element, so try:

```
  $( ".li_left_border" ).parents("ul").addClass('test');
  $( ".li_left_border" ).parents("ul").css('display', 'block');
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/L4brd0bL/

Also ensure that the HTML is already loaded when the js executes, either by putting the js code at the bottom of the HTML, or by using `$(document).ready` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $( ".li_left_border" ).parents("ul").addClass('test');
      $( ".li_left_border" ).parents("ul").css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: Hi I have edited my question to add your codes in. As you can see I think my DOM flow is correct. The first one is my own js file, the second one fires the foundation js, and the third one is your suggestion. Should be correct flow right? But it is still not working.

Comment: This is my jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/v87qajau

Comment: `global_amount` is `undefined` in your `append_cash_prize` function, because it gets initialized too late. I moved `var global_amount = 10;` on top of your script and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/v87qajau/3/

Comment: Yes I found out the problem, it is because of the too late initialized. Thanks Mario.